# AS3 point comparison

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, comparison, point

I was wondering why to equal points cannot be compared and shown as equal using '=='

e.g

```
var p1:Point = new Point( 1, 5 );
var p2:Point = new Point( 1, 5 );

trace( p1 == p2 )                   //false
trace( p1.x == p2.x, p1.y == p2.y ) //true true
trace( p1.equals( p2 ))             //true
```

It seems weird and a little pointless (pun)
Could anybody shed some light on why this is?

Comment: As a side note, `{} != {}`! But you can always compare them using ByteArray's, which will end up returning true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p1 == p2` compares the two objects and not the x and y components of the objects. Since p1 and p2 are different objects(created by new Point) `p1 == p2` returns false.

The [`.equals()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html#equals%28%29) method does a comparison of the x and y components so it returns true.

The following would return true :

```
var p1:Point = new Point(1,5);
var p2:Point = p1;
trace(p1==p2);
```

Because p1 and p2 are actually the same object.

Comment: Gah! I should have realized! Thank you for clarifying this.